# Not able to put divs side by side on Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the following markup, I'm able to put two div side by side, as seen on [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIvcE.png), but only on Chrome. [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD142.png) shows how Firefox processes the HTML. Is this a known issue I missed? How do I fix this?

```
<div style="background-color: #ffcc33;">
    <div class="entry-content" style="float: left;">
        <h3>Full Article: <a href = "<?php the_field('url'); ?> "target="_blank">Link</a></h3>
        <div id="summary_headline">
            <h3>Summary</h3>
        </div>
        <?php
            the_field('generated_summary');
            
                           wp_link_pages( array(
                               'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'inbox' ),
                               'after'  => '</div>',
                           ) );
                           ?>
        <p class="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" class="button"><?php echo esc_html('Read More', 'inbox'); ?></a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;  background-color: #eee;">
        <div id="wordmap_display" style="background-color: #a0a0a0;" >
            <h3>Word Map</h3>
            <div id="wordmap_chart"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sa_results_display" style="background-color: #f5baff;">
            <h3>Sentiment Analysis Results</h3>
            <canvas id="sa_chart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page .post-content .entry-content, .single-post .post-content .entry-content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #42ffec;
    width: 60%;
}
.post-content .entry-content {
    height: 60vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT: Got it to work. I set my outer most div to `overflow: hidden` and from my second inner div, removed `float:left`, and added `overflow:hidden`

Comment: You could just use FlexBox to place them side by side.

Comment: Your solution should be posted in an answer post instead of in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` property. It is supported in major browsers.

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.more-details {
  float: left;  
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="entry-content" style="float: left;">
        <h3>Full Article: <a href = "#" target="_blank">Link</a></h3>
        <div id="summary_headline">
            <h3>Summary</h3>
        </div>
        Dynamic markup from PHP
        <p class="read-more"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="more-details">
        <div id="wordmap_display" style="background-color: #a0a0a0;" >
            <h3>Word Map</h3>
            <div id="wordmap_chart"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sa_results_display" style="background-color: #f5baff;">
            <h3>Sentiment Analysis Results</h3>
            <canvas id="sa_chart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved my problem. See the post. This works though, so I will accept it.